# Is there a way to output SVG from MetaPost with all the fonts outlines?

Tags: metapost

Suppose, there's an arbitrary .mp file which produces an image with some TeX text labels, e.g.:

```
outputtemplate := "test.svg";
outputformat   := "svg";
beginfig (1);
  draw fullcircle;
  draw btex test etex;
endfig;
end.
```

Is there a way, without modifying anything between `beginfig` and `endfig` to get an SVG file with the outlines of all the text labels, instead of "live" text, which is yielded by mere `mpost filename.mp`?

```
...
<text font-size="9.962646">test</text>
...
```

Preferably without any external tools not provided with a full TeX Live installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took posting the question, to unexpectedly find the(an?) answer.
Adding `prologues := 3;` in the beginning of the file seems to do the trick, and the resulting SVG file from the example file above with the addition of `prologues := 3;` does contain outlines:

```
...
      <path style="fill-rule: evenodd;" d="M112.000000 -252.000000C118.000000 -401.000000,202.000000 ..."></path>
...
```